# recent display name is blank

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, display-names

Previous recent display names not showing up under **Edit Profile**. It correctly shows last used date, but the display name is just blank. Seems to affect all sites. https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current

[image]

Comment: Repro'ed on five sites, Chromium version 44.0.2403.157 m.

Comment: +1 I can re-produce too.

Comment: [The Uni's are missing!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/A4u3g.png)

Comment: Yup, confirmed it's a bug on the server itself, not browser, since the raw AJAX call (`http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/popup/past-names/[id here]`) does not contain the recent names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirmed - this was a bug introduced by a recent change in display names.  A fix will be deployed soon.